# Jquery hack to strikeout part of a string entered in a text-box

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to do the following:

A jumbled sentence is given and the user has to correct it

I have the jumbled sentence written inside a div and there is a text-box where in i get the user's answer.

Now what i want is using jquery whatever he enters in the text-box gets strikedout (<del>abc</del>) from the question so that the user knows what words he has already selected.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var orig=$('#original').html();
    $('#textbox').val(''); 
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event) {
    var x=$('#textbox').val().split(" ");   
    $('#original').html(orig);
    for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    $('#original').html($('#original').html().replace(x[i],'<del>'+x[i]+'</del>'));
    }
   }
  });

});
```

original is the id of the div containing the text and textbox the id of the textbox

This works fine for the cases where no word is repeated. But, if a word occurs more than once only the first occurrence of it is strikedout.

Can you give me a solution for the case where there are multiple occurences of a word?

For example, if the text is: posted of networking pictures can  used on wrong sites on purposes leading social to lot for problems be

when I enter: "networking sites on" words networking, sites and first occurence of on should be striked off
then when i enter on again the second occurence of it should be striked out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated, based on the the comments below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var orig = $('#original').html();
    $('#textbox').val('');
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event) {
        $("#original").html(orig);

        var x = this.value.split(" ");

        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            $("#original").contents().filter(function() {
                return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf(x[i]) >= 0;
            }).first().replaceWith(function() {
                var re = new RegExp("\\b" + x[i] + "\\b");
                return this.nodeValue.replace(re, "<del>" + x[i] + "</del>");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/E25Nd/3/

Comment: Your solution strikes out all occurrences of the word, when i enter the word once only. I want as many number of occurences of the word to be striked out as the no. of times the user has entered the word.

Comment: @AmitSingh: Ah I see, I slightly misread the question, sorry about that. I'll correct it shortly

Comment: @AmitSingh: I've updated the answer. Is that more like what you're looking for?

Comment: Your solution is nice. But in checking it I came across a problem which was in my code and is there in yours too. The problem is: if the string is "wrong on" then on entering "on wrong" doesn't strike out wrong as it striked out only on in that...it would be of great help of you could solve this

Comment: No man! the same problem still exists. Try writing "on on wrong" in the text box

Comment: Hey @AndrewWhitaker I updated your solution a bit. Very small change. This seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/E25Nd/1/. I accounted for  spaces to only match on words.

Comment: Hey @Keith.Abramo, great solution man! but the problem is with the first and the last word. they are not being striked out

Comment: Right right, my bad. Here is another solution albite, it works but I'm not a huge fan of it. http://jsfiddle.net/E25Nd/2/

Comment: @AmitSingh: Okay. I gave it one more go. Check that out, it should only replace whole words. Kind of like Keith's but uses a word boundary regex.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker: where is the solution?

Comment: seems like you are correct this time...thanx a lot! if there is any problem with this one...i ll let u knw

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaner solution

http://jsfiddle.net/bTDsd/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var orig = $('#original').html();
    $('#textbox').val('');
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event) {
        var vals = $(this).val().split(' '),
            re,
            newText = orig;

        for (var i = 0, l = vals.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (!vals[i]) { continue; }
            re = new RegExp('\(^|[^>]\)\(' + vals[i] + '\\b\)', 'i');
            newText = newText.replace(re, '$1<del>$2</del>');
        }

        $('#original').html(newText);
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem with your solution is that I wont be entering a sentence in the same order as in the text. For example, in the example given by you I might want to enter hock Ham. In this case your solution doesn't work

Comment: It will do incomplete matches as well if you don't want that then you need to adjust the regex to be `re = new RegExp('\(' + val + '[^\\w]\)', 'gi');`

Comment: Hmm sorry I didn't completely understand your question. Perhaps you can edit it to include an example of what you have, the input and expected outcome.

Comment: Ok I think I understand give me a moment

Comment: @AmitSingh I've updated the answer I think this should do what you want.

Comment: no man! your solution is striking off all Ham for one instance of Ham in user's answer...

Comment: Sorry my reading comprehension has failed me today. I'm going to take one more crack at it.

Comment: @AmitSingh I hope I got it this time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a while loop retrying your replace function.  Break when done.  Enjoy!  The g flag is an option as well.

Comment: my replace function will strikeout only the first occurence...how to make sure the second occurence is strikedout when the word is entered 2nd time?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that uses a different div to store remaining words and words that have been used already. It seems to me that looking for words that aren't struck out would be more confusing and difficult than separating them.

Script:

```
$(function(){
    var orig = $('#original').html();
    $('#original').hide();
    $('#remaining').html(orig);
    $('#textbox').val('');
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(event) {
        var originalWords = $('#original').text().split(" ");
        var words = $(this).val().split(" ");
        var selectedWords = [];
        $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
            var index = originalWords.indexOf(word);
            if(index > -1) {
                selectedWords.push(word);
                originalWords.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });      

        addWords(originalWords, $('#remaining'));
        addWords(selectedWords, $('#selected'));        
    });
});

addWords = function(words, container) {
    var allWords= '';
    $.each(words, function(idx, word) {
      allWords= allWords+ ' ' + word;
    }); 
    container.text(allWords);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="original" >StackOverflow is a programming site. programming is fun</div>
<div id="remaining"></div>
<div id="selected" style="text-decoration: line-through;"></div>
<input id="textbox" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qdWGw/

It could use some optimization, but it should work.